# Varnish add HTTP header with server IP

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I want to add a header to every response containing the Varnish server IP which served the request.

In the ancient docs there's a example of how to do [this](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/faq/http.html) (see below) but since the subroutine no longer exists I'm wondering what the modern equivalent (ie 6.*) is:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  # Add a unique header containing the cache servers IP address:
  remove obj.http.X-Varnish-IP;
  set obj.http.X-Varnish-IP = server.ip;
  # Another header:
  set obj.http.Foo = "bar";
}
```

I've tried using vcl_backend_fetch and updating remove to unset but it complains the variable cannot be unset.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work.

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
  # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
  #
  # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
  # and other mistakes your backend does.
  unset beresp.http.X-Varnish-IP;
  set beresp.http.X-Varnish-IP = server.ip;
}
```